# Inserting checkbox values from VBA form into Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a list of selected checkboxes into a spreadsheet, within this use case, a user can choose up to 15 items. This will be inserted into a certain cell which I have defined below.

I have a checkbox with the following names/values:

```
Name         Value
==========   =====
chk_week1    1
chk_week2    2
...          ...
...          ...
chk_week15   15
```

For example if the user selects chk_week1, chk_week2, chk_week4 and chk_week5, then it should be inserted into the cell as 1,2,4,5.

I've included an image how it looks like to better demonstrate it:

[image]

Each checkbox has the name and value listed in the table above. Here is the code I am using so far:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("main")

' Copy the data to the database
' Get last empty cell in column A
Set rng1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)

' Having difficulty adding the code here
' rng1.Offset(1, 7) = weeks

End Sub
```

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those the only checkboxes on the sheet?

Comment: @Excellll Yes they are the only checkboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function would return the string you're wanting to put in the cell.

```
Function CheckBoxValues() As String
    For x = 1 To 15
        If Sheets("Main").Shapes("chk_week" & x).OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value Then
            CheckBoxValues = CheckBoxValues & x & ","
        End If
    Next
    if Len(CheckBoxValue <> 0) then
       CheckBoxValues = Left(CheckBoxValues, Len(CheckBoxValues) - 1)
    end if
End Function
```

Or for the non-looping method, check Francis Dean's solution.

Comment: +1 - brilliant answer and great for dealing with lots of controls quickly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function to go through your check boxes and return a string in your desired format as such (add on the rest of the check boxes!)

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("main")

    ' Copy the data to the database
    ' Get last empty cell in column A
    Set rng1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)

    ' Having difficulty adding the code here
    rng1.Offset(1, 7) = GetWeeks

End Sub

Private Function GetWeeks() As String

    Dim weeks As String

    'Add values to the string if condition is true
    If chk_week1.Value = True Then weeks = weeks & "1,"
    If chk_week2.Value = True Then weeks = weeks & "2,"
    If chk_week3.Value = True Then weeks = weeks & "2,"
    '...
    If chk_week14.Value = True Then weeks = weeks & "14,"
    If chk_week15.Value = True Then weeks = weeks & "15,"

    'Remove the trailing comma
    If Right(weeks, 1) = "," Then weeks = Left(weeks, Len(weeks) - 1)

    GetWeeks = weeks

End Function
```

Comment: +1, but just wanted to point out that the checkboxes value is already boolean, so checking if it = true will have the same result of not bothering to check.